# How find prime numbers $p_{i}$ such $p_{1}+p_{2},p_{2}+p_{3},p_{3}+p_{4},\cdots,p_{n}+p_{1}$ is square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

**Question:**

> Let $n\ge 5$ be an odd number, show that:
>   there exist (or does not exist) primes $p_{i}\:;\:i=1,2,\cdots,n$ such that
>   $$p_{1}+p_{2},p_{2}+p_{3},p_{3}+p_{4},\cdots,p_{n}+p_{1}$$ all are square numbers.

I think these primes do not exist, but I can't prove it.

I think this problem is interesting.

I have only taken the case $n=2$ .

It is said that this problem is a hard problem from a competition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are all odd, then their remainders mod 4 must alternate 1 and 3, and it is impossible for an odd cycle to alternate.
So $p=2$ must appear.  It can appear $n$ times; or $n-1$ times and 7 appear once.
If they must all be different, then the neighbours of 2 must both be $3\mod 4$, and again alternation is impossible.

Comment: hello,I can't understand your first sentence? can you give some math latex detail?

Comment: If they are all odd, then $p_1+p_2$ is even, so it is a multiple of 4.  Either $p_1=4k_1+3$ and $p_2=4k_2+1$ or vice versa.  Then $p_3=4k_3+3$,$p_4=4k_4+1$,...,$p_n=4k_n+3$, and $p_1+p_n=4x+2$

Comment: why $p_{n}=4k_{n}+3$? I think have $p_{n-1}=4k_{n-1}+3,p_{n}=4k_{n}+1$,so $p_{1}+p_{4}=4x\equiv 0\pmod 4$ that's possible?

Comment: $n$ is odd. $p_1=p_3=p_5=...=p_n\pmod4$

Comment: Oh,I know,I forgot this condition